# Leetcode 189. Rotate Array - does creating a shallow copy means in-place?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, copy

Question Reference: https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/

I'm working on Leetcode Question 189. Rotate Array and I solved it by studying other coders' solutions. But new to coding, I still have some questions still and hope someone can help clarify these:

#1 Solution - This works:

```
k %= len(nums)
nums[:] = nums[-k:] + nums[0:-k]
```

#2 Solution - This doesn't:

```
k %= len(nums)
nums = nums[-k:] + nums[0:-k] 
#gives me the original nums which didn't change
```

But I tried #2 Solution in some Python online IDE, `nums` did change and gave back the same result as #1 Solution. Why didn't it work in Leetcode?

Another question I have is - the question requires "modify nums in-place", which in my understanding is to perform the operation without using any additional memory. But in #1 Solution, we create a shallow copy of `nums` by using `nums[:]`, does it meet the requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `x[:] = ...` just replace the contents of the `x` value without creating a new array? If you create a new array and assign it to the same variable, the old array hasn't been replaced. It's still there.

Comment: @tadman Yes it does.

Comment: From the comment in the Python Leetcode i.e. *rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead*, Leetcode is only examining the original array, thus only an inplace solution will be evaluated correctly by Leetcode.  The 2nd solution creates a new array that is not examined by Leetcode.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/5987

Comment: P.S. `[:]` on the right side of the equals sign will create a copy but on the left side it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `nums[:]` you just replece the old array values without creating a new one and the error I guess is given because of the requirement.

Hope thats help.